# VBA - Copying and Pasting - Running Error

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

Please see my code below.
I have a list of data in columns A to R in `sheet7`.
I need to copy the data from row 1 columns A-F to the first 12 rows of sheet6, starting in row E.
After doing this I need to transpose the data in `sheet7` from row 1 columns G-R to sheet6 to column Q (rows 1-12).

Thanks in advance. Question is when running code I am getting a "Run-time error 13, Type Mismatch". When using F8 to locate issue I cannot see where it occurs. I get past the msgbox part of code.

This needs to be repeated many times to complete all data.

```
Sub copy1()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    j = 2
    MsgBox (j)

    For i = 2 To 1000
        Worksheets(Sheet7).Activate
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 6)).Select
        Selection.copy
        Worksheets(Sheet6).Activate
        Range(Cells(j, 5), Cells(j + 11, 5)).PasteSpecial
        Worksheets(Sheet7).Activate
        Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(i, 18)).Select
        Selection.copy
        Worksheets(Sheet6).Activate
        Range(Cells(j, 17).Address).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
        j = j + 12
    Next i    
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question? what is working, what is going wrong? Did you get any errors and where? This is not a "here is my code … fix it" website. Note: Always use `Long` Excel has more rows than integer can handle.

Comment: When you say `worksheet2` do you mean `Sheet6`?  Also [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Yes Darren, apologies, I've edited in the Q now.

Comment: Worksheet names need to be in `""` so `Worksheets(Sheet7)` should be `Worksheets("Sheet7")` same for `Sheet6`. I also recommend to find a tutorial on how to avoid `.Select` and `.Activate` there are many on Google. Also using `Option Explicit` would be a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that `Range` needs either two cells or an address of the cell to work. And you need `Range` for the PasteSpecial part. See yourself, how the following would not work:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Range(Cells(1, 1)).Select
End Sub
```

But this would work nicely (all selecting `A1`):

```
Sub TestMe()
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1)).Select
    Range(Cells(1, 1).Address).Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Range([A1].Address).Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    Cells(1).Select
    [A1].Select
End Sub
```

Thus, change your code from:
`Range(Cells(j, 17)).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True`

To:
`Range(Cells(j, 17).Address).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True`

Further interesting topics:

- [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)
- [Why Use Integer Instead of Long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long)

Comment: The conversion from a range (`Cells(j, 17)`) to a string (`Cells(j, 17).Address`) and back to a range (`Range(Cells(j, 17).Address)`) is pointless.  Just use `Cells(j, 17).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True`

Comment: @chrisneilsen - not exactly pointless, the idea is to show what happens in the `Range()` and why `Range(Cells(1,1))` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to have some potential issues. Here is an improved version of it. Since you did not mention the exact issues, see if this one works..

```
Sub copy1()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 2
    MsgBox (j)

    For i = 2 To 1000
        Worksheets(Sheet7).Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 6)).copy
        Worksheets(Sheet6).Range(Cells(j, 5), Cells(j + 11, 5)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Worksheets(Sheet7).Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(i, 18)).copy
        Worksheets(Sheet6).Range(Cells(j, 17),Cells(j, 17)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues Transpose:=True
        j = j + 12
    Next i   
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Consider declaring the parents completely. E.g. writing         `Worksheets(Sheet7).Range(Worksheets(Sheet7).Cells(i, 1), Worksheets(Sheet7).Cells(i, 6)).copy`, otherwise the code considers the activesheet. To understand what I mean, try to run your code by activating `Sheet1` first.

Comment: @shash, I have tried this code however I still get a "Run-time error 13, Type Mismatch".

Comment: This cannot work `Worksheets(Sheet7)` because of missing `""` I hardly recommend to always use `Option Explicit` then you would have immediately seen this error. In your code `Sheet7` and `Sheet6` are variables and both are empty and cast to `0` in this case so it is the same like writing `Worksheets(0)`.

Comment: Peh - Thanks for the feedback and apologies for the basic questions... I am new to this (as you can probably see by my code). I have now turned on Option Explicit.

Comment: Peh - I have updated the code as you have said and I'm now struggling with a  "Subscript out of range" error 9. any advice?

Comment: PEH, thanks for the correction, I overlooked that thinking it 'Sheet7' was a string variable.
James, one possible reason for this error could be mismatch in the name of the sheets. The sheet that you refer to has to be named exact same way i.e."Sheet7". 
Another way to refer to sheets is by using something like ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i) 
where i is an integer index of the sheet you're looking for.

Comment: James can you please mark the things that helped you, as useful.

Comment: The issue was that I missed out the ".Address" when defining the range...